# Raising complex event using Moq in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, moq, mstest

The following code should be self explanetory: we have an adaptor, who consumes events from the transport (layer), which holds the MessageRegistrar (object type because we can't tell it's type, and basically because this is legacy code :-) ). The transport layer have a concrete which have an event.
I want to test a case where the event is triggered, so..

After hours of trying to figure why it won't pass, I present the following challenge:

```
[TestFixture]
public class AdaptorTests
{
    public delegate void TracksEventHandler(object sender, List<int> trklst);

    public class MyEventHolder
    {
        public virtual event TracksEventHandler EventName;
    }

    public interface ITransport
    {
        object MessageRegistrar { get; }
    }

    public class MyTransport : ITransport
    {
        private readonly MyEventHolder m_eventHolder;

        public MyTransport(MyEventHolder eventHolder)
        {
            m_eventHolder = eventHolder;
        }

        public virtual object MessageRegistrar
        {
            get { return m_eventHolder; }
        }
    }

    public class MyAdaptor
    {
        private readonly ITransport m_transport;

        public MyAdaptor(ITransport transport)
        {
            EventTriggered = false;
            m_transport = transport;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            MyEventHolder eventHolder = m_transport.MessageRegistrar as MyEventHolder;
            if (eventHolder != null)
                eventHolder.EventName += EventHolderOnEventName;
        }

        private void EventHolderOnEventName(object sender, List<int> trklst)
        {
            EventTriggered = true;
        }

        public bool EventTriggered { get; private set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void test1()
    {
        Mock<MyEventHolder> eventHolderMock = new Mock<MyEventHolder> {CallBase = true};

        Mock<MyTransport> transportMock = new Mock<MyTransport>(eventHolderMock.Object) {CallBase = true};

        MyAdaptor adaptor = new MyAdaptor(transportMock.Object);
        adaptor.Connect();

        MyEventHolder eventHolder = transportMock.Object.MessageRegistrar as MyEventHolder;
        Mock.Get(eventHolder).Raise(eh => eh.EventName += null, new List<int>());

        Assert.IsTrue(adaptor.EventTriggered);
    }

    [Test]
    public void test2()
    {
        Mock<MyEventHolder> eventHolderMock = new Mock<MyEventHolder> { CallBase = true };

        Mock<MyTransport> transportMock = new Mock<MyTransport>(eventHolderMock.Object) { CallBase = true };

        MyAdaptor adaptor = new MyAdaptor(transportMock.Object);
        adaptor.Connect();

        MyEventHolder eventHolder = transportMock.Object.MessageRegistrar as MyEventHolder;
        Mock.Get(eventHolder).Raise(eh => eh.EventName += null, null, new List<int>());

        Assert.IsTrue(adaptor.EventTriggered);
    }

}
```

My question is: why wont the test (at least one of them) pass?

**EDIT @151217-0822** Addded 'adaptor.Connect()' to the original post (still won't fix the issue).

### WORKAROUND

Credits to @Patrick Quirk: Thanks!!

For those encountering the same issue: after I understood what Patrick-Quirk detected, and trying couple of failed workarounds, I've ended up adding the following verified fix: 'eventHolder.FireEventNameForTestings(new List());':

```
    public class MyEventHolder
    {
        public virtual event TracksEventHandler EventName;

        public virtual void FireEventNameForTestings(List<int> trklst)
        {
            TracksEventHandler handler = EventName;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, trklst);
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void test3()
    {
        Mock<MyEventHolder> eventHolderMock = new Mock<MyEventHolder> { CallBase = true };

        Mock<MyTransport> transportMock = new Mock<MyTransport>(eventHolderMock.Object) { CallBase = true };

        MyAdaptor adaptor = new MyAdaptor(transportMock.Object);
        adaptor.Connect();

        MyEventHolder eventHolder = transportMock.Object.MessageRegistrar as MyEventHolder;
        eventHolder.FireEventNameForTestings(new List<int>());

        Assert.IsTrue(adaptor.EventTriggered);
    }
```

HTH..

Comment: Are you missing a call to `Connect()`?

Comment: In the example yes, in real code - no.
Still, adding connect won't solve the issue.

Inspired by your insights I've ended up adding 'eventHolder.FireEventNameForTestings' to workaround the issue, and it worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `CallBase` and `Raise()` have an unexpected (to me) interaction.

When you are attaching an event handler to a virtual event on a mock, you go through [this code in Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/b2cf2d303ea6644fda2eaf10bad43c88c05b395f/Source/InterceptorStrategies.cs#L251):

```
if (invocation.Method.IsEventAttach())
{
    var delegateInstance = (Delegate)invocation.Arguments[0];
    // TODO: validate we can get the event?
    var eventInfo = this.GetEventFromName(invocation.Method.Name.Substring(4));

    if (ctx.Mock.CallBase && !eventInfo.DeclaringType.IsInterface)
    {
        invocation.InvokeBase();
    }
    else if (delegateInstance != null)
    {
        ctx.AddEventHandler(eventInfo, (Delegate)invocation.Arguments[0]);
    }

    return InterceptionAction.Stop;
}
```

You can see that if `CallBase` is `true`, then it will add your handler to the *concrete object's* event (via `invocation.InvokeBase()`).  If `CallBase` is `false`, it will add it to an invocation list on the *mock* (via `AddEventHandler`).  Now let's look at [the code for `Raise()`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/b2cf2d303ea6644fda2eaf10bad43c88c05b395f/Source/Mock.Generic.cs#L513), which gets the event object from the `Expression` and then calls [`DoRaise()`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/blob/b2cf2d303ea6644fda2eaf10bad43c88c05b395f/Source/Mock.cs#L929):

```
internal void DoRaise(EventInfo ev, EventArgs args)
{
    // ... parameter validation

    foreach (var del in this.Interceptor.InterceptionContext.GetInvocationList(ev).ToArray())
    {
        del.InvokePreserveStack(this.Object, args);
    }
}
```

See the call to `GetInvocationList()`? That retrieves the invocation list from the mock that I mentioned above.  This code never invokes the actual event on the base object.

So, it seems there's no way to raise an event on a mocked object where `CallBase` is set to `true`.

The only workaround I see, if you require `CallBase` being `true`, is to add a method to your concrete `MyEventHolder` to trigger your event.  Obviously what you posted is a simplified example so I can't give you more guidance than that, but hopefully I've shown you why what you have does not work.